# Facebook graph api fetching friends photos tagged in empty data set

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to retrieve the photos where my friends who are using the app are tagged in.

When I call the graph API I always get an empty data set on `GET /{user-id}/photos`

Giving [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/) : "By default, reading from the photos edge includes all photos a person has been tagged in."

I triple check the permissions, I can't see what I'm missing :

Here are the reading permissions the app requests :

`public_profile`, `email`, `user_friends`, `user_groups`, `user_likes`, `user_photos`, `uses_posts`

Does it still possible to di since with API 2.4 ? Or do I miss something ?

Here is a part of the app settings of one of my friends on his facebook account :

[image: App settings]

All requiered permissions seem to be there.

Comment: Phrasing in documentation suggests that you can not read this data for other users, but that you need to use the user’s own access token instead.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to implement a system on a server side that allow me to retrieve other user's access token ? Like saving all facebook's access tokens of the app's users in a database ? And retrieve them to be able to fetch the photos where they're tagged in ? Or am I stuck to do what I want to do ?

Comment: If the data you want is only available using the user’s own access token, then you will have to store them (and probably extend them before doing so) and use them when you are making those requests, yes.

Comment: Alright, thanks @CBroe . I'll have a look in this direction then.

Comment: @BoilingLime have you been able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue now